# How to update crl for tomcat

Tags: tomcat, pki

How to create and update the crl file for tomcat server.xml?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) to create the crl, but I don't know if it can be hot-updated.